# java knowledge gap - OptaPlanner generics related - what do I miss?

Tags: java, generics, optaplanner

I'm busy with an OptaPlanner project, and made a modification which is exposing a java (generics) knowledge gap of mine. In the OptaPlanner framework, there is a set of generic classes using the Solution_ type. In my project, I wanted to have that Solution_ extend from SolutionBase, which is a class I made myself and which holds some common characteristics I want all my Solution classes to have.

So whereas before, I had my business layer class declared generically:

```
public abstract class CommonBusinessLayer<Solution_> extends LoggingMain
```

it now has to be declared:

```
public abstract class CommonBusinessLayer<Solution_ extends SolutionBase> extends LoggingMain
```

However, in that business layer class, I have a problematic statement that I don't know how to write. before that change, the line

```
DefaultSolverFactory<Solution_> solverFactory = (DefaultSolverFactory<Solution_>)SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("some string");
```

compiled just fine (the createFromXmlResource- method is part of the OptaPlanner framework). But this now doesn't compile any longer because I made Solution_ inherit from SolutionBase. When looking into the framework's return type of `SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("some string")`, it's obvious that I can't make the (generic) return type any more type-specific.

So how do I solve this problem?

(FWIW, I realise that I need some more java -generics- education, and in the meantime ordered Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" book, yet I hope to be helped out a little quicker here).

Answer (score 1):

In this declaration

```
public abstract class CommonBusinessLayer<Solution_ extends SolutionBase> extends LoggingMain
```

`Solution_` is a type *variable*, nothing to do with the `Solution_` class and actually *hides* the `Solution_` class from the code in `CommonBusinessLayer`.

Best practice is to use a single capital letter for type variables, usually `T`.

Change your class to:

```
public abstract class CommonBusinessLayer<T extends SolutionBase> extends LoggingMain
```

---

If the type is always going to be `Solution_` (or a subclass thereof), don't make `CommonBusinessLayer` generic and instead use `Solution_` in your code and rely normal inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Still, I think that Solution_ (even named as T, this doesn't change a lot I think) needs to subclass from SolutionBase in my case, to be sure Solution_ DOES subclass my SolutionBase class when used in my CommonBusinessLayer call ? On the other hand, the OptaPlanner framework itself doesn't guarantee this : it doesn't return a more specific SolutionBase- inheriting class. So I may have misunderstood (or not understood) you, but I still ask myself if I can do this anyhow ?

Comment: What is the scope of such a kind of type variable like in this case Solution_ ? In other words, if I use Solution_ in one class, can I use it in other classes ? Like e.g. if using "Solution_ extends SolutionBase" in one class, can I just use Solution_ in other classes, and will it just as well extend SolutionBase ?

Comment: Its scope is all instance fields and methods of the class. It's just a type name, so it has no effect outside the class. I strongly recommend naming it `T`. You'll make your code easier to read and it will match online examples in case you need further help.

Comment: Yes, you learned me this, and I catch the spirit, and outside of OptaPlanner I'll (try to) stick to this spirit. On the other hand, Solution_ is used in the OptaPlanner framework code to suggest the type variable really could be any Solution type (without forcing it to inherit from any kind of superclass, as a Solution class can really be any class abiding to the usual general properties any Solution has). So in this use case, I think it makes sense to stick to the framework's used "Solution_", so as to keep the mental clue it really *is* any class sticking to the Solution class properties.

Comment: I also noted that a class within the (generic) class, using the same (T / Solution_) generic type variable, needs to have <Solution_ extends SolutionBase> repeated, the same Solution generic type variable doesn't seem to be "remembered" from the outer class.